# Entropy of $\{X_1,\ldots,X_T\}$ where $X_1,\ldots,X_T \in_R [Q]$

Tags: information-theory

I have a noiseless T-user multiple access channel. Let $[Q] = \{1, \dots , Q \}$. The users send symbols $X_i ∈[Q], i = 1, \dots , T$ . The channel is defined as follows
$$(X_1, X_2, \dots , X_T) → Y$$

$Y=\cup_{i=1}^T X_i$, $X_i$ are i.i.d uniform

For example: $(1, 2, 3) → \{1, 2, 3\}$, $(1, 1, 2) →\{1, 2\}$

How to find $I(X_1, \dots , X_T; Y )$ ?

Actually I can't even understand what is the distribution of $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $Y$ is determined by $X_1,\ldots,X_T$, the mutual information is just the entropy of $Y$.

We can compute the probability that $Y = \{i_1,\ldots,i_\ell\}$ as follows. There are $S(T,\ell)$ ways to partition $[T]$ into $\ell$ non-empty subsets (without order on the subsets); these are [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind). There are $\ell!$ ways to assign $i_1,\ldots,i_\ell$ to the $\ell$ parts. In total, the probability is $\ell! S(T,\ell)/Q^T$. Therefore
$$
H(Y) = \sum_{\ell=1}^{\min(Q,T)} \binom{Q}{\ell} \frac{\ell! S(T,\ell)}{Q^T} \log \frac{Q^T}{\ell! S(T,\ell)}.
$$